# discord.js: Issue with adding usernames to string

Tags: javascript, promise, concatenation, discord.js

I have written the following code for a Discord bot using discord.js. The purpose of the code I am attempting to write is for the bot to reply with a list of usernames whose id's are specified in another .json file. This is what I have written.

```
if(command === "privlist")
{
    var msg = ""
    msg += "[Privileged Users]\n"

    // iterate through the array of id's
    config.privileged.forEach(function(item, index) {
        msg += index + ": ";

        // fetch the user associated with the id in the array
        client.fetchUser(item).then(User => {
            // add the name of the user into the string to be outputted
            msg += User.username + "#" + User.discriminator;
        });

        // include the user id as well
        msg += " <" + item + ">\n";
    });

    // send the message
    message.channel.send(msg);
}
```

The expected reply from the bot should be something like this.

```
[Privileged Users]
0: Merlin#8474 <172734241136836608>
1: Spring Voltage#2118 <255109013383938048>
2: masterhunter56#2561 <243167201471889409>
3: brett#4582 <123957558133129217>
```

But instead, this is what I get.

```
[Privileged Users]
0:  <172734241136836608>
1:  <255109013383938048>
2:  <243167201471889409>
3:  <123957558133129217>
```

I tried adding `console.log(User.username)` after the `msg += User.username + "#" + User.discriminator;` line, and that makes the names show up correctly in the console.

I can even do `message.channel.send(User.username)` after `msg += User.username + "#" + User.discriminator;` and that will send each of the names as it's own message.

I just can't seem to concatenate that `User.username + "#" + User.discriminator` to the `msg` string.

Comment: `client.fetchUser(item).then(User` is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

As [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) said, you used an asynchronous function. Which means that this line:
`msg += " <" + item + ">\n";` won't wait for  `client.fetchUser(item).then(User` to end to continue.

I think that this should work :

```js
if(command === "privlist")
{
    var msg = ""
    msg += "[Privileged Users]\n"

    // iterate through the array of id's
    config.privileged.forEach(function(item, index) {
        msg += index + ": ";

        // fetch the user associated with the id in the array
        client.fetchUser(item).then(User => {
            // add the name of the user into the string to be outputted
            msg += User.username + "#" + User.discriminator;
            // include the user id as well
            msg += " <" + item + ">\n";
        });
    });

    // send the message
    message.channel.send(msg);
}
```